# How to install a font on arch linux + doom emacs

Tags: fonts, doom

I am trying to be able to use [this font](https://www.bibleplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Proto_Sinaitic_15.zip) on Arch Linux + Doom Emacs. So far what I did is the following:

- Download and unzip font to ~/.local/share/fonts/
- run fc-cache

The font is working on libreoffice writer, it is shown as "Protosinaitic 1", however when I try that on emacs it doesn't work.

I will split my question in two parts.

My first question is: how do I use this font for PDF export?

This is a short version of my headers that should work as a minimal example:

```
#+latex_compiler: xelatex
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \setmainfont[BoldFont={Cardo Bold}, ItalicFont={Cardo Italic}]{Cardo}

#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{polyglossia}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \setmainlanguage{english}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Protosinaitic 1}
```

I would like to produce some text similar to this

[image: mixed text with english and hebrew characters]

I "guess" that it should render with some code similar to this (not sure though:

```
The hebrew word \texthebrew{av} is spelled...

or for full paragraphs:

\begin{hebrew}
a b c d e f g
\end{hebrew}\newline
```

When I do an export to latex/pdf via xelatex, I expect to show the characters as on the [second column here](https://www.bibleplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Paleo-Hebrew_Fonts_Chart_by_Kris_Udd.pdf).

My second related question is the following: would it be possible to change the font for a section of the text for visual editing within Emacs? Similar to changing a paragraph only font on libreoffice. I am not talking about PDF exporting on this second question, but only for reading within Emacs.

Could you please help me out, I have never done this on Emacs. Thank you very much.